Weird model deformations in pose mode
This is my first time using Rigify to try and rig a low poly model and everything so far has been working aside from small issue. The pelvis area of my model seems to have one point that refuses to move and causes weird distortion on my model. I've tried going through and changing bones, re weight painting and messing with bones but nothing I seem to do fixes the issue. I initially thought it was an issue with the bones for the tail but even after deleting the tail bones the issues persists. I would appreciate any insight to what could be wrong because I am just lost and don't know where I should turn.

Maybe select All on your model in Edit mode then hit M > Merge by Distance in case you have overlapping vertices? - It's difficult to see what the problem is from your image so it might be an idea to share your Blend file here.  You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the full link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it.
